# Jquery swip to proceed to next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

I use this function to enable swipe for navigation on my website.

Now it needs to read and proceed to the url with the class 'next'

```
<li class="next"><a href="/webcams/tirol/2/a/b">Next</a></li>
```

Here I need you help to create that.

```
$(function () {
  $(document).on('mousedown', 'div', function (e) {
    var ref = arguments.callee;
    var handle = $(this);
    var startX = e.clientX;
    var startY = e.clientY;
    handle.off('mousedown', ref);
    handle.on('mouseup', function(e) {
      handle.off('mouseup', argument.call);
      handle.on('mousedown', ref);
      var endX = e.clientX;
      var endY = e.clientY;
      var distanceX = Math.(endX - startX);
      var distanceY = Math.(endY - startY);
      if (distanceX > 50) {
        handle.trigger((endX > startX) ? 'swipeRight' : 'swipeLeft');
      }
      if (distanceY > 50) {
        handle.trigger((endY < startY) ? 'swipeDown' : 'swipeUp');
      }
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
  });
  $(document).on('swipeRight', 'div', function(e) {

  });
  $(document).on('swipeLeft', 'div', function(e) {

  });
  $(document).on('swipeUp',  'div', function(e) {

  });
  $(document).on('swipeDown',  'div', function(e) {

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `swipeRight` callback do:

```
window.location = $(".next a").attr("href")
```

First this code gets the element with a class of `.next` with children of `a` then gets the `href` property using the `.attr()` function and redirects the browser to the value of the href.

Comment: this won't work, .next is doesn't contain a href attr. check my answer bellow.

Comment: I've changed the code so that it targets the a in the .next class

Comment: Ok, changed it. It works. How can I check whether there is a class called 'next'?

Comment: @mark You don't have two because jQuery will handle any errors. But if you want to you could do `!!$(".next")[0]` it will evaluate to true when there is a class called next.

Answer (score 0):

You can just query the anchor tag (a) which is a direct child of list with class next:

```
$(document).ready(function() {             
  console.log($('li.next > a').prop('href'));      
});
```

**Working fiddle:http://jsbin.com/ibIGoma/6/edit**